# Entity Framework defaultConnectionFactory for MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

The below configuration works fine when I specify the connectionString name as a parameter to the base constructor. Because I want to be able to change the default provider later on without recompiling, I want to set it in my `app.config` instead, but I have no idea what to provide as `type` for `defaultConnectionFactory`.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQL" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=abc;UID=root;PASSWORD=;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"></defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Exception:

> Failed to set Database.DefaultConnectionFactory to an instance of
>   the 'MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework' type
>   as specified in the application configuration. See inner exception for
>   details.

Inner exception (translated, VS is set to English but some messages are still in my language):

> Could not load type "MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory" in
>   assembly "EntityFramework"

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx) states that the assembly name follows after the colon, thus I also tried `MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6`, giving me this exception:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0.

I'm using EF6, MySql.Data & MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 6.8.3.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `name` property of the connectionString **must** be the same as your context. This works fine:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NAMEOFYOURCONTEXT" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=abc;Uid=root;Pwd='';" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: How we are suppose to change at runtime from mssql to mysql or mysql to mssql? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998212/dynamically-change-update-setdefaultconnectionfactory-and-setproviderservices-en). Please let me know.