# How to use MySQL EF 6 with connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I use MySQL EF 6 (MySQL.Data.Entity package) to connect to MySQL DB. Everything is ok if I use the constructor connectionStringName `:base("MyContext")`. But it does not work, if i use connectionString directly `:base("server=localhost;port=3306;database=wordpress;uid=root")`. The application raise error `System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'port'.`

My project need use directly connection string. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thank you

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    static MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }

    public MyContext()
        //:base("server=localhost;port=3306;database=wordpress;uid=root;password=") not work
          :base("MyContext")   // it worked if using connectionStringName
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Currently you're using [`DbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.) constructor which accepts either connection string name from web.config or any directly assigned connection string:

```
public DbContext(
    string nameOrConnectionString
)
```

The latter argument string has major problem which it doesn't provide any way to include database provider name in use (you can't provide `providerName` value there, i.e. `MySql.Data.MySqlClient`), hence EF automatically selected default provider defined by `defaultConnectionFactory` in web.config like this:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
</entityFramework>
```

Since the default database provider still being set to SQL Server, it doesn't accept `port` as its keyword in connection string, hence throwing `ArgumentException`.

To fix this issue, just [change default connection factory to `MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45217166/c-sharp-entity-framework-keyword-not-supported-port), so that MySQL is now set as default provider for all connection strings passed to `DbContext` (assuming you're using EF 6):

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    <providers>
       <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></provider>
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

**Note:** If you provide name of connection string stored inside web.config, it will work since `connectionString` element has `providerName` attribute which will passed to EF `DbContext`:

```
<add name="MyContext" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;database=wordpress;uid=XXXXX;pwd=XXXXX" />
```

Similar issues:

[Dynamic MySQL database connection for Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277677/dynamic-mysql-database-connection-for-entity-framework-6)

[Entity Framework defaultConnectionFactory for MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604633/entity-framework-defaultconnectionfactory-for-mysql)