# Visual Studio 2015 Only Shows SQL Server Connections When Trying to Create an ADO.NET Entity Model Class

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, entity-framework-6

I have previously created an instance of a MySQL database as described in [this question on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/196988/science-fiction-wall-of-fame-shame). I have completed the database, and I’m ready to create the application using C# in Visual Studio 2015.

The only question I’ve found here on stackvoverflow.com that seems relevant is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604633/entity-framework-defaultconnectionfactory-for-mysql).

I have been using MySQL Documentation from these pages:

- Connector Instalation using [Nuget](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-installation-binary-nuget.html)
- Connector / [NET Entity Framework 6.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)

Environment is Windows 10, The regedit image shows the .net framework version. I upgraded MySQL to version 8.0.11 earlier this week.
Package Manager Console:
PM> get-package

Id                                  Versions                  ProjectName
--                                  --------                  -----------
EntityFramework                     {6.2.0}                   bkInventory2App
Google.Protobuf                     {3.5.1}                   bkInventory2App
MySql.Data                          {8.0.11}                  bkInventory2App
MySql.Data.EntityFramework          {8.0.11}                  bkInventory2App

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQLBKLibInventory" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" connectionString="SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=pacswlibinvtool;UID=root;PASSWORD=******;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"/>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
          type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"/>
      <!-- provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
          type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" -->
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**Dot Net Version**
[image]

**Add ADO.NET Class**
[image]

**Choose Model Contents**
[image]

**Choose Data Connection**
[image]

**Choose Data Source**
[image]

**ODBC Data Administrator**
[image]

**Installed MySQL Applications**
[image]

**Database in MySQL WorkBench**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please note in the second to last image, the one showing the installed MySQL Applications, that MySQL for Visual Studio is not installed. Installing MySQL Visual Studio corrected this particular configuration problem.